# StructureMap - EF initialize with variable from another class

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a Product  logic class that uses a `DbContext` to add and insert products.

I also have a `ProductImporter` class that loops through a list of products from a file and calls the `addProduct` in the `Product` class. It does this in a transaction so either all the products are added or none. Pseudo is found below.

The product class has two constructors. The first that takes in a dbcontext and the second initializes a new dbcontext. I use the first constructor that passes the `DbContext` from the `ProductImporter` to enable the transaction.

```
var dbContext...

ImportProducts() {

   Product p = new Product(dbContext); 

   dbContext.BeginTransaction


   While(moreProducts)

        p.addProduct();


   End transaction

}
```

**My question is: how can I use structure map to satisfy the two cases**:

1. Inject a new instance of the product class whenever the app needs to add one product.
2. Inject the `Product` class in the `ImportProducts` method above to use the same `DbContext`. Effectively, replacing the line below by having structure map inject the product class and having it use the same `DbContext` as the `ProductImporter` class.

   ```
   Product p = new Product(dbContext);
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code for any of your classes I can only speculate - but it seems you are mixing your data classes and logic/service classes - this can lead you into hard to maintain and hard to implement issues (the latter is what you are experiencing).

My suggestion is to make your product class only hold the data - no logic at all. You can use the **Repository Pattern** to do this. I found a link that gives you an example: http://web.archive.org/web/20150404154203/https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

> Please read the above link and research the pattern - it will save you a lot of time and  headaches. If you understand the pattern well enough, check out **Generic Repositories** they will save you even more time and make your code an order of magnitude easier to maintain.

The point here is that you have a separate class for the data/entity/model and another for the logic/services/(working with the database).

You then only need your repository to have the `DbContext` injected and the repository can be injected to the importer.

For example:

*This is untested and adlib code. I am only trying to provide an example of the solution.*

```
public class ProductImporter
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;    

    public ProductImporter(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.__productRepository = this._productRepository;
    }

    public void AddProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            this._productRepository.Add(product);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```